# Hide resource files in game making

Tags: c++

I notice that in many game folders, I cannot find the resource files (sounds, game scripts, textures...). Is that because I don't see it or the programmers have hidden them somewhere?

I'm learning to make my first game in SDL2.

Comment: This depends on the game... and it isn´t a programming question.

Comment: It depends on the build system used. Windows is known to allow the inclusion of resources in the executable for example. Anyway the programmer is free to organize its data as he wants. But this question is currently too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will often be compressed into .cab or other kinds of archival formats to decrease required space and provide tamper protection.